# Symfony2 + AJAX return source code

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony

I made an ajax code to send the form data to the controller  but it's returning source code instead.

I am using FOSJsRoutingBundle to generate my route in my js code (i installed and used it like the doc said), this is working and return this when it's call on my js

> /xampp/folder/web/app_dev.php/chat/

I render my form in twig like this

```
{{ form_start(form, {'action': '{{ path("chat_page") }}', 'method': 'POST'}) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
<input type="submit" value="Send">
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

My js code look like this

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = Routing.generate('chat_page');
    console.log(url);
    console.log($('#chat_message').val());

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: $('form').attr('method'),
        data: $('#chat_message').val(),
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

    $('#chat_message').val('').focus();
});
```

My controller (probably not used when ajax is done) is this one

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @Route("/chat/", name="chat_page", options={"expose"=true})
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $chatForm = $this->createForm(ChatType::class);

    $client = $this->get('elephantio_client.socketio_key');
    $elephantIOClient = $client->getElephantIO();

    $elephantIOClient->initialize();

    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {

        $chatForm->handleRequest($request);

        $chatData = $chatForm->getData();
        dump($chatData);
        $elephantIOClient->emit('chat message', ['msg' => $chatData]);
    }

    $elephantIOClient->close();

    return $this->render('chat/index.html.twig', [
        'form' => $chatForm->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

I think it's a problem with the url (who seems good) who don't call my controller but i don't know what.

I readed some topic about ajax with symfony and it's all the time like i made. If you have any ideas to help me to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly doesn't work with your code? What did you expect to be done and what happened instead?

Comment: The code is working. I expect to get the data i put on the form but i get the source code of my page instead. My console log return source code, it's like my `data: $('#chat_message').val(),` return page source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's rendering your HTML code because in your controller you are rendering your HTML code with this :

```
return $this->render('chat/index.html.twig', [
    'form' => $chatForm->createView(),
]);
```

You need to add a return response inside your if clause to return something else when it's an ajax request :

```
if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {

    $chatForm->handleRequest($request);

    $chatData = $chatForm->getData();
    dump($chatData);
    $elephantIOClient->emit('chat message', ['msg' => $chatData]);
    return new Response("ok");
}
```

Comment: Oh yes it was it and i understand why it was returning source code right know. Thanks for your explaination and your help